# Ultimate Marvel vs. Capcom 3 DLC

Tags: ultimate-marvel-vs-capcom-3

There's a way to still obtain the DLC for Ultimate Marvel vs. Capcom 3?
Because the icon for the game appears in the PS Store, but no description or info is avaible for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any DLC for UMvC3 is unavailable including the digital download of the game itself due to Capcom losing the license from Disney to do stuff with Marvel.

Related article: http://www.eventhubs.com/news/2014/mar/22/capcom-expired-contract-means-we-cant-create-or-alter-umvc3-content-marvel-says-fans-will-have-wait-and-see-combining-universes/

EDIT: You can now purchase UMvC3 and all DLC on Playstation 4.